# Sort through numbers

Tags: text-processing, sort

I need to sort a list by the ISBN NUMBER (the third column) from an input file to a `file.sh` and sent to an out file (`file.out`).
The input file (`file.input`) would have a list

```
Donald Smith,Fire Lands,97868545414459
Adam Barry,The Armies,97564325678855
Jennifer Lelan,Childhood dreams,97546766544237
```

using a looping structure to process the data and the titles `Author` `Name of book` `ISBN`.

The result

```
Author                   Name of Book               ISBN

Jennifer  Lelan    Chilhood Dreams   97546766544237
Adam Barry          The Armies             97564325678855
Donald Smith        Fire Lands              97868545414459
```

Answer (score 6):

This first part is a new answer added in 2023. The old answer is still available after the divider.

```bash
$ mlr --icsv --implicit-csv-header --opprint  label Author,Title,ISBN then sort -n ISBN file.input
Author         Title            ISBN
Jennifer Lelan Childhood dreams 97546766544237
Adam Barry     The Armies       97564325678855
Donald Smith   Fire Lands       97868545414459
```

This uses [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to read the data as header-less CSV, add labels to the three fields, sort the records numerically on the `ISBN` field, and output all data in a "pretty printed" tabular format.  Since Miller is CSV-aware, this would cope with quoted fields containing embedded commas and newlines, etc.

Use `'Name of Book'` (quoted) in place of `Title` for the longer header, as in the question. Use `--otsv` instead of `--opprint` to generate tab-separated value output.

Redirect the command with `>file.output` to overwrite or create the file `file.output`.

---

First of all, you would *not* loop over this data: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716)

If the only commas in the file are the commas that delimit the fields, then

```sh
sort -t ',' -k3n -o file.output file.input
```

would sort the data numerically on the number in the third column. The output would be written to `file.output`.

For the given data, `file.output` would look like

```
Jennifer Lelan,Childhood dreams,97546766544237
Adam Barry,The Armies,97564325678855
Donald Smith,Fire Lands,97868545414459
```

To further process this data, one could consider using an `awk` program.  Since you have not specified what kind of processing you'd like to do, the following just extracts the data into variables (not really necessary)  for each line and prints them:

```sh
sort -t ',' -k3n file.input |
awk -F ',' '{ author=$1; title=$2; isbn=$3;
              printf("Author: %s\nTitle: %s\nISBN: %s\n",
                     author, title, isbn) }'
```

Note that there is no need to store the sorted data in an intermediate file in this case.

The output given the data in the question:

```
Author: Jennifer Lelan
Title: Childhood dreams
ISBN: 97546766544237
Author: Adam Barry
Title: The Armies
ISBN: 97564325678855
Author: Donald Smith
Title: Fire Lands
ISBN: 97868545414459
```

For getting the data into nice looking columns, and with dashes in the ISBN number, you don't need `awk`. The following uses `sed` for the formatting of the ISBN numbers and `column` to format the columns:

```sh
sort -t ',' -k3n file.input |
sed -E -e 's/,([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{5})/,\1-\2-\3-/' |
column -s ',' -t
```

The output will be

```
Jennifer Lelan  Childhood dreams  975-4676-65442-37
Adam Barry      The Armies        975-6432-56788-55
Donald Smith    Fire Lands        978-6854-54144-59
```

Note that the ISBN numbers look a bit wonky.  That's because they are 14 digits long.  *Real* ISBN numbers [are either 10 or 13 digits long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number), and the above code assumes that they are 13 digits (or at least 12 digits).

To add columns headers:

```sh
sort -t ',' -k3n file.input |
{ echo 'Author,Name of book,ISBN'
  sed -E -e 's/,([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{5})/,\1-\2-\3-/'
} |
column -s ',' -t
```

Which produces

```
Author          Name of book      ISBN
Jennifer Lelan  Childhood dreams  975-4676-65442-37
Adam Barry      The Armies        975-6432-56788-55
Donald Smith    Fire Lands        978-6854-54144-59
```

... using no explicit loops in the shell.

Answer (score 4):

`sort` is clearly the best tool for sorting.

If `awk` is required, you can use GNU awk:

```
gawk -F, '
    {line[$NF] = $0} 
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
        for (isbn in line) print line[isbn]
    }
' file
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html and https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html